# Where is the sensible place to modify response data in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Using a combination of React, Redux and Thunk, I have the following:

**actions.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';
import { API_PATH } from '../constants/Config';

export function coursesLoaded(courses) {
    return { type: types.COURSES_LOADED, courses };
}

export function fetchData() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return $.getJSON(API_PATH).then((response) => {
            dispatch(coursesLoaded(response.result));
        });
    };
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import { routerReducer as routing } from 'react-router-redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
    courses: [],
};

function main(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.COURSES_LOADED:
            return {
                ...state,
                courses: action.courses,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ main, routing });

export default rootReducer;
```

The two snippets above sit well, and i feel like they align to the intentions of Redux. I want to now do some modifications to the fields that are returned in the response, before they hit the containers.

For example, the response might be:

```
[
    { code: "R101", name: "Intro to Redux", author: "Dan" },
    { code: "R102", name: "Middleware", author: "Dan" },
]
```

And I want to change it to (simple example for simplicity):

```
[
    { code: "R101", name: "Intro to Redux", author: "Dan", additionalProperty: "r101_intro_to_redux" },
    { code: "R102", name: "Middleware", author: "Dan", additionalProperty: "r102_middleware" },
]
```

**Research thus far**

**Option One**
Looking at the async example on Redux, I can see there is a light touch to the response here:
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/actions/index.js#L33

**Option Two**
Looking at other Stackoverflow questions, it leads me to believe keeping it out of the actions makes more sense, as reducers should be what modifies state (but perhaps this doesn't really count as state?):
[Redux - where to prepare data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430389/redux-where-to-prepare-data)

**Option Three**
I have an inclining that this is the job of middleware - being that's how normalizr handles it, but I can't find any non-passive middleware examples. If middleware is the go here, should the middleware be dispatching some kind of SET_STATE action, or is it free to update state right there in the middleware?

**EDIT**

Experimented with some middleware, such as:

```
import { lowerCase, snakeCase } from 'lodash';
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

    export default store => next => action => {
        if(action.type == types.COURSES_LOADED) {
            action.courses = action.courses.map((course) => {
                course.additionalProperty = snakeCase(lowerCase(`${course.code} ${course.name}`));
                return course;
            });
        }
        return next(action);
    }
```

It seems to work fine - is this indeed the intention of middleware? Original question holds - where it the ideal spot?

Comment: I'd suggest extracting the API fetch logic into a `DataService`, which is also capable of modifying the returned JSON object. As a result your `$.getJSON(API_PATH)` becomes `DataService.getMyData(path)`, and the `then()` already has the correctly formatted data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As for me I do this kind of things in the action (either `coursesLoaded` or `fetchData`).

Here are the reasons why:

- This is not store material, this is just external data management, so nothing to do with reducers which are supposed to change the STATE of the store
- Different reducers might actually need the same corrected data, imagine you have another reducer that gathers all `additionalProperty` for achiving purposes for example, so doing it in the action ensures that the right data is sent to all reducers.
- This is not a typical job for a middleware, this is only specific to one action, whereas middleware would be useful if it was used the same way by a bunch of actions. Plus using middleware is more obscure and separates it from the reader. Having action-> reducer is much more simple and does not have any major disadvantage.

Comment: Hmm, I really like that thought process. I haven't used react/redux enough yet to reason about how to tackle various problems yet

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a [selector](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data), and keep the original in redux store.

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  courses: mySelectorThatAddsFields(state.courses),
}
```